# Angular 1.x: methods for serialized object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deep-copy, prototype-chain

I'm using Angular 1.x and I have defined two "classes": Order and OrderItem. I added a bunch of methods to them and I want to keep those methods when the API returns an object "of the same type". I know the serialized object that I get from the API is not of the same type and I know it will not have any methods. That's why I need to find a way to add those methods or to copy the property values from the object returned from the API to a new object created using the function constructor.

**In summary:**

-I have defined some methods for Order and OrderItem.

-When I create objects using those function constructors everything is good.

-When I get an object from the API, it has no methods (for obvious reasons) and I need to add them.

**Ideas:**

A) Copy property values from the object returned by the API to an object created using the function constructor. I tried Angular.copy but it only worked for the first level (Order) and not for the second level (OrderItem).

B) Assign prototypes to the object returned by the API.

C) Move the methods away from Order and OrderItem, to an OrderManager object for example, but I don't like this option as it is not a natural approach in OOP.

What is the best way to go?

Comment: Are the OrderItem known properties of Order? e.g `function Order(oi1,0i2){this.oi1 = oi1;this.oi2=oi2}`

Comment: you should just pass the object returned from api to this constructor?

Comment: Order has methods like getTotal() that iterates over the OrderItems and OrderItem has methods like getTotal() that considers the unit price and quantity, among others.

Comment: I can pass the object returned from the API to the constructor but then I need to define how to copy the value of the properties for Order and OrderItem.